# Package operation failed in package management

Tags: apt, package-management

When I try to install or remove any application from ubuntu software center I get this error: `Package Operation Failed`.

As suggested in many posts in this forum I did this `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  codeblocks codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-contrib-dbg codeblocks-dbg codeblocks-dev libwxsmithlib-dev libwxsmithlib0-dev
Suggested packages:
  libwxgtk2.8-dev wx-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libwxsmithlib-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  codeblocks codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-contrib-dbg codeblocks-dbg codeblocks-dev libwxsmithlib0-dev
6 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 243 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/84.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 73.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 159995 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libwxsmithlib-dev (from .../libwxsmithlib-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libwxsmithlib-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/wxsmith/contrib/include/wx/propgrid/advprops.h', which is also in package wxsmith-headers 10.05-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error:   subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to replace codeblocks-dev 10.05-1 (using .../codeblocks-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement codeblocks-dev ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/codeblocks/scripting/sqplus/SqPlusConst.h', which is also in package codeblocks-headers 10.05-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error:   subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libwxsmithlib-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In GUI  under **Package operation failed** dialogue box I get this:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 159995 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libwxsmithlib-dev (from .../libwxsmithlib-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libwxsmithlib-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb (--unpack):  
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/wxsmith/contrib/include/wx/propgrid/advprops.h', which is also in package wxsmith-headers 10.05-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to replace codeblocks-dev 10.05-1 (using .../codeblocks-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement codeblocks-dev ...  
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb (--unpack):  
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/codeblocks/scripting/sqplus/SqPlusConst.h', which is also in package codeblocks-headers 10.05-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwxsmithlib-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_10.05-2_i386.deb
Error in function:   
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks:
 codeblocks depends on libcodeblocks0 (= 10.05-1); however:
  Version of libcodeblocks0 on system is 10.05-2.
 codeblocks depends on codeblocks-common (= 10.05-1); however:
  Version of codeblocks-common on system is 10.05-2.
dpkg: error processing codeblocks (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks-contrib:
 codeblocks-contrib depends on libwxsmithlib0 (= 10.05-1); however:
  Version of libwxsmithlib0 on system is 10.05-2.
 codeblocks-contrib depends on codeblocks (= 10.05-1); however:
  Package codeblocks is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing codeblocks-contrib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwxsmithlib0-dev:
 libwxsmithlib0-dev depends on wxsmith-dev (= 10.05-1); however:
  Package wxsmith-dev is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libwxsmithlib0-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks-dbg:
 codeblocks-dbg depends on codeblocks (= 10.05-1); however:
  Package codeblocks is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing codeblocks-dbg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks-contrib-dbg:
 codeblocks-contrib-dbg depends on codeblocks-contrib (= 10.05-1); however:
  Package codeblocks-contrib is not configured yet.
 codeblocks-contrib-dbg depends on codeblocks-dbg (= 10.05-1); however:
  Package codeblocks-dbg is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing codeblocks-contrib-dbg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Code::Blocks is broken on your system, best to remove and reinstall it:

```
sudo dpkg -P all_codeblocks_pacakges_here
```

Same goes for libwxsmith.

Comment: I did `sudo dpkg -P codeblocks` this destroyed me: at least code::blocks used to run with `codeblocks` in the terminal now; it doesn't run and the problem persists.

Comment: Did you remove *all* the codeblocks and libwxsmith packages with dpkg -P? If not, do so and reinstall them afterwards with apt-get.

Comment: I removed all packages with unmet dependencies related to codeblocks shown in the **Package Operation Failed** dialogue box. Then reinstilled it. You put me out of a great misery. Thank you.